# R language: how to plot shapefiles with open limits?

Tags: r, plot, mapping, limit, shapefile

A dummy question I'm asking after trying to fix it by myself and googleing for a while. I need to plot several maps, which involve adding countries' limits. So far, I have used the following script:

```
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
library(raster)
library(geodata)

e <- extent(-76.5, -60.0, -3.0, 3.5)

paises <- c("BRA", "COL", "ECU", "VEN")
for(i in 1:length(paises)){
     if(i == 1){
          shps0 <- gadm(paises[i], level=0, path = tempdir(), version="latest", resolution=1)
     } else {
          temp <- gadm(paises[i], level=0, path = tempdir(), version="latest", resolution=1)
          shps0 <- rbind(temp, shps0)
     }
}
shps0 <- crop(shps0,e)
```

This yields the following map (without the colored arrows) of the region among Colombia, Brazil, Venezuela Ecuador, and Peru:
[image]

However, I would like to remove the artificial limits (black lines indicated by the red arrows) from the plot and display a continuous representation of the data, including the portions where the countries farther "continue" (indicated by the green arrows), something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the current version of terra. So the first thing to do is to update that package. The issue you are having that the axes of the plot follow the canvas size, not the map size. In the current version of "terra" that is not the case.

```
library(geodata)
library(terra)
pols <- gadm(c("BRA", "COL", "ECU", "VEN"), level = 0, path = tempdir())
e <- ext(-76.5, -60.0, -3.0, 3.5)
```

If you just wanted to add these polygons as lines on top of an existing plot (map), say or raster `x` that I create below, you can do

```
x <- rast(e, vals=1)
plot(x)
lines(pols)
```

If you want to start by plotting lines you could do

```
plot(e, border=NA)
lines(pols)
```

You can also do

```
plot(pols, xlim=c(-76.5, -60.0), ylim=c(-3.0, 3.5), axes=FALSE)
plot(pols, ext=c(-76.5, -60.0, -3.0, 3.5), axes=FALSE)
```

That is, you do not need to crop the polygons. If you do, @margusl solution to use `as.lines(pols)` is fine, but it should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For just plotting and for this particular case it probably makes no difference, but `mask()` transforms `SpatVector` returned by `gadm()` to raster. Though you can keep vector shapes if you just transform polygons to lines first. With `terra`, which is loaded by `geodata` anyway, it might look something like this:

```r
library(geodata)
#> Loading required package: terra
#> terra 1.7.23
library(terra)

shps0_poly <- gadm(c("BRA", "COL", "ECU", "VEN"), level = 0, path = tempdir())
shps0_poly
#>  class       : SpatVector 
#>  geometry    : polygons 
#>  dimensions  : 4, 2  (geometries, attributes)
#>  extent      : -92.00854, -28.84764, -33.74632, 15.91248  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#>  coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#>  names       : GID_0  COUNTRY
#>  type        : <chr>    <chr>
#>  values      :   BRA   Brazil
#>                  COL Colombia
#>                  ECU  Ecuador
as.data.frame(shps0_poly)
#>   GID_0   COUNTRY
#> 1   BRA    Brazil
#> 2   COL  Colombia
#> 3   ECU   Ecuador
#> 4   VEN Venezuela

shps0_lines <- as.lines(shps0_poly) |> 
  crop(ext(-76.5, -60.0, -3.0, 3.5))
shps0_lines
#>  class       : SpatVector 
#>  geometry    : lines 
#>  dimensions  : 4, 2  (geometries, attributes)
#>  extent      : -76.5, -63.37228, -3, 3.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#>  coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#>  names       : GID_0  COUNTRY
#>  type        : <chr>    <chr>
#>  values      :   BRA   Brazil
#>                  COL Colombia
#>                  ECU  Ecuador
as.data.frame(shps0_lines)
#>   GID_0   COUNTRY
#> 1   BRA    Brazil
#> 2   COL  Colombia
#> 3   ECU   Ecuador
#> 4   VEN Venezuela

plot(shps0_lines)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Great, but how do I create an object (to be used several times) with it?

Comment: You can break pipes (`|>`) where ever it fits your purpose and assign as usual.
Updated the answer to be a bit more verbose.

Answer (score -2):

Well, problem fixed: I must use `mask` instead of `crop`... thanks anyway

Comment: Hello, this is not an answer. This should be a comment. And you have enough reps to `add a comment` (see the link do so).